# Jquery UI Autocomplete index number in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I wrote some auto complete code who works, the list is showing up, but now I need to make those clickable, I have an ID stored in the JSON who I call over ajax, but I can't get it in the 'select' section from the autocomplete, so I declared an array and filled it with the IDs in the 'source' mapping section. But I need to know the index number of the clicked/selected suggestion.

Here is my code:

```
// Declarations
var i   = 0;
var j   = 0;
var ids = []; // Array of ids

$('#search-bar').autocomplete(
{
    source : function(requete, reponse){
    $.ajax(
    {
            url : 'search/' + $('#search-bar').val(), // JSON source 
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                reponse($.map(data, function(objet)
                {
                    ids[i] = objet.id;  // Filling up the array
                    i++;
                    return objet.name;
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui)
    {
        window.location = 'project/' + ids[j];  // Link the the project page
        j++;    // not working
    }
});
```

Here is an example of returned JSON:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Project 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Project 2"}]
```

Someone knows how to replace my 'j' variable with the index of the clicked/selected entry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return an object in the `source` method, then in the `select` method use the `id` of the selected item to construct the url:

```
$('#search-bar').autocomplete(
{
    source : function(requete, reponse){
    $.ajax(
    {
            url : 'search/' + $('#search-bar').val(), // JSON source 
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                reponse($.map(data, function(objet){
                    return {
                        label: objet.name,
                        value: objet.id,
                       id: objet.id
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui)
    {
        window.location = 'project/' + ui.item.id;
    }
});
```

Comment: the idea is that `response` method can return a more complete object that contains also the ID of the item

Comment: What do I need to return then ? Because with your code it says me syntax error on line `value: objet.id,`

Comment: sorry, I've missed a return